# Use same parameter multiple times in sql query

Tags: python, sql, parameters, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc and Microsoft SQL Server

I am trying to replicate a stored procedure in python where this query is executed for every @currentSurveyId

```
SELECT *
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        SurveyId,
                        QuestionId,
                        1 as InSurvey
                    FROM
                        SurveyStructure
                    WHERE
                        SurveyId = @currentSurveyId
                    UNION
                    SELECT 
                        @currentSurveyId as SurveyId,
                        Q.QuestionId,
                        0 as InSurvey
                    FROM
                        Question as Q
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM SurveyStructure as S
                        WHERE S.SurveyId = @currentSurveyId AND S.QuestionId = Q.QuestionId
                    )
                ) as t
                ORDER BY QuestionId
```

In Python, I so far have:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT UserId FROM dbo.[User]""")
allSurveyID = cursor.fetchall()

for i in allSurveyID:
    p = i
    test = cursor.execute("""SELECT *
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        SurveyId,
                        QuestionId,
                        1 as InSurvey
                    FROM
                        SurveyStructure
                    WHERE
                        SurveyId = (?)
                    UNION
                    SELECT 
                        (?) as SurveyId,
                        Q.QuestionId,
                        0 as InSurvey
                    FROM
                        Question as Q
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM SurveyStructure as S
                        WHERE S.SurveyId = (?)AND S.QuestionId = Q.QuestionId
                    )
                ) as t
                ORDER BY QuestionId""",p)

for i in test:
    print(i)
```

The parameter works when used once (if I delete everything from UNION onwards). When trying to use the same parameter in the rest of the query, I get the following error:('The SQL contains 3 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Is it possible to use the same parameter multiple times in the same query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If reusing the same parameter value, simply multiply a one-item list of the parameter:

```py
cursor.execute(sql, [p]*3)
```

Consider also refactoring your SQL for `LEFT JOIN` (or `FULL JOIN`) requiring two qmarks:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       ISNULL(S.SurveyId, ?) AS SurveyId, 
       Q.QuestionId, 
       IIF(S.SurveyId IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS InSurvey 
FROM Question Q
LEFT JOIN SurveyStructure S
  ON S.QuestionId = Q.QuestionId 
  AND S.SurveyId = ?
ORDER BY Q.QuestionId
```

Possibly even for one parameter:

```sql
SELECT MAX(S.SurveyId) AS SurveyId, 
       Q.QuestionId, 
       IIF(S.SurveyId IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS InSurvey 
FROM Question Q
LEFT JOIN SurveyStructure S
  ON S.QuestionId = Q.QuestionId 
  AND S.SurveyId = ?
GROUP BY Q.QuestionId, 
         IIF(S.SurveyId IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)
ORDER BY Q.QuestionId
```

Answer (score 1):

pyodbc itself only supports "qmark" (positional) parameters (ref: [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyodbc/zuXrEgk_14A)), but with T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server) we can use an *anonymous code block* to avoid having to pass the same parameter value multiple times:

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

sql = """\
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @my_param int = ?;
SELECT @my_param AS original, @my_param * 2 AS doubled;
"""
results = crsr.execute(sql, 2).fetchone()
print(results)  # (2, 4)
```